# Eloquent calculate if I have more results left

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a Products API. I need to return a collection of products and a variable telling me if I have more results starting from the last the answer has just returned me to show or hide a load more button. This is all I have until now:

```
$query = Product::query();
$query->where('category_id', $request->get('category_id'));
$query->orderBy('order', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->skip($skip)
    ->take($take);
```

And this is how I return it:

```
return [
    'products' => $query->get(['id', 'name', 'front_image', 'back_image', 'slug']),
    'has_more' => ????
];
```

How can I calculate the has_more?

Comment: any reason you cannot use eloquents pagination `->paginate($take)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to query the database twice:

```
$query = Product::query()
    ->where('category_id', $request->get('category_id'))
    ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc');

$count = $query->count();
$hasMore = $skip + $take < $count;
$models = $query->skip($skip)
    ->take($take)
    ->get(['id', 'name', 'front_image', 'back_image', 'slug']);

return [
    'products' => $models,
    'has_more' => $hasMore
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the count of the entire records and then simply do the check for has more like so:

```
    <?php
        $query  = Product::query()
                  ->where('category_id', $request->get('category_id'));
                  ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
                  ->orderBy('name', 'asc');

        $count  = $query->count();

        return [
            'products' => $query->skip($skip)
                                ->take($take)
                                ->get(['id', 'name', 'front_image', 'back_image', 'slug']),
            'has_more' => ($hm = ($count - ($take + $skip))) > 0 ? $hm : false
        ];
```